# How to show progress bar while xmlHttpRequest properly?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

The problem is that when I'm trying to show progress bar(just .gif) I don't see it. When execute step by step using chrome dev tools. I see it. When run without  breakpoints I don't. It seems like it didn't manage to draw gif before start request but I don't understand why. the code is the following:

```
startLoadingAnimation();
var bill = model.save(data);
stopLoadingAnimation();
```

where `startLoadingAnimation();` is:

```
function startLoadingAnimation()
{
    var imgObj = $("#loadImg");
    imgObj.show();

    var centerY = $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() + imgObj.height())/2;
    var centerX = $(window).scrollLeft() + ($(window).width() + imgObj.width())/2;

    imgObj.offset({top:centerY, left:centerX});
    }
```

and `stopLoadingAnimation()` is:

```
function stopLoadingAnimation() 
{
    $("#loadImg").hide();
}
```

and `model.save(data)` finally goes to

```
SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl, forseArray);
```

Comment: model.save() is an async call ... it's going to execute that function and then immediately call stopLoadingAnimation. Probably a "duplicate" of an existing asynchronous question.

Comment: @BryanRay but async in _sendSoapRequest is false or it is async anyway?

Comment: it's async ... it's going to fire of that HttpRequest and then continue going about its business ...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to probably have your save method take a `callback` function as a second option ... that then gets passed down in to your `_sendSoapRequest` `callback` parameter and then you can take advantage of your `stopLoadingAnimation` function.

**Pseudo-code**

```
var bill = model.save(data, { callback: function() { stopLoadingAnimation(); } });
```

You'll need to modify your existing `.save()` function to handle that second parameter of options (if it doesn't already accept something).